# How to color the shared space between two images?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need this idea for my new game concept but i can't find solution by myself and even in unity forum.

Please is there any Unity developer that can help me?

[image: EXAMPLE]

Thank You

Comment: That's a good result! You should explain how it works and submit it as an answer to your own question!

Comment: I rolled back your edit. It is inappropriate here to add SOLVED to the title or add the solution to the question. If you found an answer and want to share it, do so by writing an answer in the space below that is provided for that purpose. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

The solution I used to accomplish this result is to use the 2 pass stencil shader and modify the camera background to solid color - white.

There are the passes in the shader (the color is hardcoded). Then just create a material with this shader and place it onto the meshes.

Yes this version works only with the right shape of meshes. So when you want a circle or a triangle then export the mesh from a 3D modelling engine and use it in Unity with this shader.

```
Shader "Custom/NewSurfaceShader"{
Properties {}
SubShader 
{
    Tags { "RenderType"="Geometry" }

    Pass
    {
        Stencil
        {
            Comp always
            Pass IncrSat
        }

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag

        struct appdata
        {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        struct v2f
        {
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
        };

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        float4 _MainTex_ST;

        v2f vert (appdata v)
        {
            v2f o;
            o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
            o.uv = v.uv;

            return o;
        }

        fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
        {
            fixed4 col = fixed4(0, 0, 0, 1);
            return col;
        }
        ENDCG
    }

    Pass
    {
        Stencil
        {
            Ref 1
            Comp Less
        }

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag

        struct appdata
        {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        struct v2f
        {
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
        };

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        float4 _MainTex_ST;

        v2f vert (appdata v)
        {
            v2f o;
            o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
            o.uv = v.uv;

            return o;
        }

        fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
        {
            fixed4 col = fixed4(1, 1, 1, 1);
            return col;
        }
        ENDCG
    }
}
```

}

[image: This is the result]

---

### Edit:

Just upgraded the shader, in this solution it works with the sprite shapes, too. You don't need to create meshes anymore. The only drawback is that now it is on 3 shader passes.

```
    Shader "Unlit/NewUnlitShader"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 100

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            struct appdata_t
            {
                float4 vertex   : POSITION;
                float4 color    : COLOR;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 vertex   : SV_POSITION;
                fixed4 color    : COLOR;
                float2 uv  : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;

            v2f vert (appdata_t v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                o.color = v.color;

                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                // sample the texture
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                col = col * i.color;

                if(col.a < .5f)
                {
                    discard;
                }

                return col;
            }

            ENDCG
        }

        Pass
        {
            Stencil
            {
                Comp always
                Pass IncrSat
            }

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            struct appdata_t
            {
                float4 vertex   : POSITION;
                float4 color    : COLOR;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 vertex   : SV_POSITION;
                fixed4 color    : COLOR;
                float2 uv  : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;

            v2f vert (appdata_t v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                o.color = v.color;

                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                // sample the texture
                fixed4 col = fixed4(0, 0, 0, 1);
                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }

        Pass
        {
            Stencil
            {
                Ref 1
                Comp Less
            }

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            struct appdata_t
            {
                float4 vertex   : POSITION;
                float4 color    : COLOR;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 vertex   : SV_POSITION;
                fixed4 color    : COLOR;
                float2 uv  : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;

            v2f vert (appdata_t v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                o.color = v.color;

                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 col = fixed4(1, 1, 1, 1);
                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @AliBouka yes those were only passes, just edited and pasted the whole shader code.

Comment: GREAT WORK BROTHER... Now all work perfect.. Is it possible add my Skype : ali.friend40 or Facebook : zouhir.abada

Comment: @AliBouka nice, if you like this solution then mark it as useful, too ;)

Comment: Yep i did :D BUT i got message i can't now because i'm new here :D

Comment: Now i passed 19 rep .. i gave u " Vote Up" .. Good Luck

Comment: One last question.. Two shared space between two black objects will give white color.. BUT i was looking if 3 objects or more shared same area it will stay black and not change to white. Please any ideas how to do that ?

Comment: @AliBouka Actually it was't specified in your question at all. But it is just a matter of the stencil code.

Comment: Yes i'm so sorry. Is it possible help me or edit the shader to create my idea. Thank You.

Comment: i did it alone :D ...I just duplicated the second part of code then changed "Ref 2"

Comment: @AliBouka you see, easy as that. Congrats.

Comment: Hello Brother :). One question... Can you help me replace color white to transparent color. Changing 1 to 0 didn't work " fixed4 col = fixed4(1,1,1,0); " :) ANY IDEAS !!